# I'm Beginner, I want to add meta tag to my WP site to show site Link Previews

Tags: wordpress, meta-tags

Can anyone help me to add a plugin or add-ons to my wp site to show Link Previews in Telegram app ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you check out [these Telegram-related plugins from the WordPress.org](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=telegram)?

Comment: Let me explain more specifically, When you type a website link, Telegram app shows to you a link preview of that website, So when I type my website address there is no Link preview , What should I do that I can see link preview for my website!?

Comment: @Saeidza Updated answer!

Comment: Thank you for your update, I installed a SEO plugin all pages have link preview but the first page has not any link preview when I entered my website like , Telegram doesn't show link preview for my website! :(

Comment: The SEO plugin might have a parameter that lets you customize the settings for your front page. Otherwise, it might be possible to examine where the SEO plugin inserts tags on the pages that work, then customize the front page with a similar tag. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you.I'm using Yoast plugin...It helps me too much.